# How to use cast on few columns whose name match a certain criteria

Tags: dataframe, casting, pyspark

In my dataframe I need to change few columns data type to long.
Below code gives me null values.
How do I fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5etV.png)

```
df.select(*(F.col(x).cast("long").alias(x) for x in df.columns if x.startswith('fib_')))\
.withColumn("Fib", F.greatest(*[x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('fib_')])).show()
```

Comment: Difficult to help you without a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Added the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

With reproducible example

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
data = [(1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0), (0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), (2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)]
schema = StructType([
    StructField("Fib_12", StringType()),
    StructField("Fib_13", StringType()),
    StructField("Fib_14", StringType()),
    StructField("Fib_15", StringType()),
    StructField("Fib_16", StringType()),
    StructField("Fib_17", StringType()),
])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
df
# DataFrame[Fib_12: string, Fib_13: string, Fib_14: string, Fib_15: string, Fib_16: string, Fib_17: string]
```

Solution with explanation.
The example DataFrame you posted had column names like `FibNN`, whereas you use a string-pattern `fib_` to match. Thus, I changed the example data to have column names like `Fib_NN` and using `re.match` and a regex-pattern `(?i)fib_`, which is case-insensitive. `re.match` return `True` for positive regex-matches. The `(?i)` makes the string-pattern to match case-insensitive. If you are still getting `NULL` values, the likely culprit is that all of your `Fib_NN` columns contain a `NULL` value.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, greatest
import re
select_cols = [col(x).cast('long').alias(x) for x in df.columns if re.match('(?i)fib_', x)]
collect_cols = [col(x) for x in df.columns if re.match('(?i)fib_', x)]
result = (
    df.
        select(*select_cols).
        withColumn(
            'Fib_max',
            greatest(*collect_cols)
        )
)
result.show(truncate=False)
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+                             
|Fib_12|Fib_13|Fib_14|Fib_15|Fib_16|Fib_17|Fib_max|
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
|1     |1     |0     |0     |2     |0     |2      |
|0     |0     |0     |2     |0     |1     |2      |
|0     |0     |1     |0     |0     |1     |1      |
|2     |0     |1     |0     |0     |0     |2      |
|0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0      |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

Comment: With the reproducible example? Or with your own data?